# Problemm with Primefaces' Layout and layoutUnit when using Datatables

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable, jstl

i recently started using primefaces to make something fast for a small project for college and i opted for the `<p:layout>` component.
after using the same code form the official documentation which is the same everywhere i search, i added a `datatable` to the center `layoutUnit` but when deployed the `datatable` was not shown and no exception was generated.

i did inspect the result webpage and i found the `datatable` but empty and with 0px height

any ideas ? how to fix it ?

note: that the `datatable` works fine outside any `LayoutUnit` componenet

This is the Layout code

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="60" style="border : dashed;">
                <h:form>
                    <p:menubar style="background-color: #034257" toggleEvent="hover">

                        <p:menuitem label="Home" action="#{BackingBookService.retrieveBooks()}" value="Home" style="float: right;background-color: azure"
                                    icon="ui-icon-home"/>
                        <p:submenu label="Categories" style="background-color: azure" model="">
                        </p:submenu>
                        <p:submenu label="Authors" style="background-color: azure">
                            <p:menuitem value="Youtube" url="http://www.youtube.com" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Break" url="http://www.break.com" />
                        </p:submenu>

                        <p:menuitem value="USERX" for="logoutbutton"></p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem  id="logoutbutton" label="Logout" action="#{BackingBookService.retrieveBooks()}" value="Logout" style="float: right;background-color: azure"
                                     icon="ui-icon-disk"/>
                    </p:menubar>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" >

            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="300" >
                <h:outputText value="Left content" />
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="200" >
                <h:outputText value="Right Content" />
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <h:outputText value="Books By Categories"></h:outputText>
                <ui:component>
                        <p:dataTable var="Books" value="#{BackingBookService.bookList}" initMode="immediate" style="width: 100%;">
                            <p:columns value="#{BackingBookService.columns}" var="column"
                                       sortBy="#{column.property}" filterBy="#{column.property}">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    #{column.header}
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{Books[column.property]}" />
                            </p:columns>
                        </p:dataTable>
                </ui:component>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
```

And this is how the webpage is 
[webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGrki.jpg)

So the `datatable` should be already under the books by categories `outputtext` but it is not

Comment: why do u have <ui:component> around <p:dataTable>?

Comment: Because i was trying to make the datatable work though i  don't really know what `<ui:component>` does. but it didn't work anyway so i omitted it the current code doesn't have the `<ui:component>`.